Mocha-Selenium-JavaScript: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reporter')
While integrating Allure reports with Mocha, i am trying to incorporate a takescreenshot function in selenium and to add that screenshot in my Allure reports. Its giving me an error of TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reporter') when called with mocha.reporter
this is my Takescreenshot.js
const fs = require('fs');
const { allure } = require('allure-js-commons');

const takeScreenshot = async (driver, screenshotName) => {
    try {
        const screenshot = await driver.takeScreenshot();
        fs.writeFileSync(`./allure-results/${screenshotName}.png`, screenshot, 'base64');
        
        if (allure) {
            allure.createAttachment(`${screenshotName} Screenshot`, Buffer.from(screenshot, 'base64'), 'image/png');
        } else {
            console.error('Allure object is not defined.');
            console.log('Allure object:', allure);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error capturing screenshot:', error);
    }
};

module.exports = {
    takeScreenshot
};


i am calling this function in my Test.js
        try{
            mocha.reporter(AllureReporter, {
                allureReportPath: 'allure-results', // Directory where Allure results will be saved
                disableWebdriverStepsReporting: false,
                disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false
            });
        }catch (error) {
            console.error('Error initializing Allure Reporter:', error);
            throw error;
        } 

Before execution it gives the error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reporter')
if i remove this codeblock and use it by default in my package.json the error is returned through takescreenshot function as "Allure object is not defined.
Allure object: undefined"

Apparently I was able to fix this issue by making changes in my Takescreenshot.js.
below are the changes that i made
const fs = require('fs');
const { allure } = require("allure-mocha/runtime"); //i was calling require('allure-js-commons')
console.log('Allure object:', allure);

const takeScreenshot = async (driver, screenshotName,) => {
try {
    const screenshot = await driver.takeScreenshot();
    fs.writeFileSync(`./allure-results/${screenshotName}.png`, screenshot, 
'base64');
    
    if (allure) {
        allure.attachment(`${screenshotName} Screenshot`, Buffer.from(screenshot, 'base64'), 'image/png'); //i was calling allure.createAttachment
    } else {
        console.error('Allure object is not defined.');
        //console.log('Allure object:', allure);
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error capturing screenshot:', error);
}
};

module.exports = {
takeScreenshot
};

these changes i have found on https://allurereport.org/docs/attachments/ but once integrated my VS is showing a strikethrough on allure.attachment showing that its deprecated and i need to look out for updated one.
I am unable to find the updated one as of now but the changes made in code is getting the job done so far. if anyone could find anything please share.
calling  mocha.reporter(AllureReporter in my Test.js, i have removed it and moved this config to package.json file as shown below
"mocha": {
"parallel": false,
"reporter": "allure-mocha",
"reporterOptions": {
  "resultsDir": "allure-results"
}
}

